# What is the best surface to use the Magic Mouse on?

Tags: hardware-recommendation, mouse

I got the Magic Mouse along with my MacBook, tried using it for awhile, but I got disenchanted with it quickly. Instead of having sliding pads, it has two hard plastic bars, which make it unpleasant to use on most surfaces. I`ve tried it on my wooden table (little bit of dirt scratched it up), paper (too much friction), cloth-covered mousepad (has some issue with correctly tracking), even on the surface of my MacBook (awkward), but none of them seem to be working too good. What surface was the Magic Mouse designed to work on, and which surfaces are really good for using it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you need a [gaming surface](http://www.amazon.com/s/url=field-keywords=gaming+mouse+pad), some of them was made specially for use with Apple mouses:

## Cupertino Mouse Pad — $15


They say it's made by company located at Cupertino, California. Also it works (as a surface).

[image: Cupertino Mouse Pad just lies on a table]

---

## MacPadd — $25


It's basically just a piece of finished aluminum and I guess it will feel the same as a top surface MacBook.
[Tom'sHardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/macpadd-qms-business-scam-fraud,8972.html) says that something's weird with their delivery, but maybe it's [b.s](http://gizmodo.com/5470573/a-rebuttal-to-macpadd-accusations). It's also reviewed on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gliKYZvumLM).

[image: MacPadd pad]

---

## Just Mobile AluPad — $45

They clim it's made exclusively for Apple products and there are a couple of positive reviews on Youtube for this one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d1w4kgx-wY) and [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VefKyK3tEHE). They say that the surface is pleasant on touch.

[image: Just Mobile AluPad and mouse on it]

---

## a Better Table

Consider finding a better table than one that you use now. Just grab your MacBook and mouse and go furniture shop that you like and find a table which fits you the best. You will get biggest possible working surface and as a bonus you can improve  ergonomics of your workplace. And of course keep your table clean (I know it's hard. I have a cat:).

Answer (score 5):

> cloth-covered mousepad (has some issue with correctly tracking)

You'll need a mousepad with a printed pattern on it, or a very coarse thread count.  The Magic Mouse was designed foremost with low power consumption in mind, and not for twitch gaming.  It sometimes can't see the individual threads on some cloth mousepads well enough to track.  A busy printed pattern will be better than a large two color company logo.

You can buy almost any of the printed mousepads at the Apple store and get good results.

If the feel was ok, and tracking was the only issue, I suggest simply swapping the mousepad out for one with a printed pattern.

You can also test this out without buying a new one by wrapping your old mousepad in some old clothing or tshirt of yours and testing it.  If that fixes the problem, get a new mousepad, or glue a square of shirt material to the top of your existing mousepad.

Answer (score 3):

Put **Scotch tape** on the bottom of your Magic Mouse (as recommended by @Will) and use a **binder cover** as your "mousepad".

I had a spare 3-ring binder and simply cut off the cover with scissors, then used some more tape to keep it from sliding around my desk.

It sounds hack, but it's cheap, and **works really well**! Much less friction, but still accurate and precise.

[image: Magic Mouse with Scotch tape on bottom to reduce friction]

[image: 3-ring binder cover as mousepad for Magic Mouse]

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks for all the suggestions above! I've tried many of these (and others) but eventually my solution to this (surprising but irritating) problem is a simple A4 clear plastic paper wallet or folder - the type which have an opening on one long and one short side but with no fasteners or closing poppers - the wallets usually have a very slightly textured surface (these seem to work better than a totally smooth surface). Put a single sheet of paper inside - colour of your choice to match your mood or decor (I use white as I have a white desk) - and finally use some clear tape to fix to the desk (landscape or portrait) and hey presto - almost silent, smooth and accurate Magic Mouse gliding!

Answer (score 2):

I use a cloth covered mousepad with a printed pattern.  Seems to work just fine.  Also seems to work on a very clean (non-sticky) non-wood office desk surface.

Rubbing just a bit of skin oil from your fingers onto the plastic bars on the bottom of the mouse may or may not help your feel for the sliding.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a cloth mousemat, but found the cover of a glossy magazine to work really well.  It glides nicely with no scratching sounds, and it tracks perfectly.  So now, for aesthetic reasons, I used a blank sheet of glossy laser printer paper.  Presumably you could print something to have a custom design or colour, but I have not tried that myself.

Answer (score 2):

I find that a laminated piece of paper works quite well for me as a Magic Mouse surface.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions on using a glossy magazine cover made me thing about glossy paper for printing photographs. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

I use a neat little product called [Fliders](http://www.fliders.com).  They are tiny pads that attach to the bottom of your mouse and actually replace a mousepad.  They are made from a soft material that reduces the noise and makes moving the mouse smoother on the desk.

Answer (score 1):

I have an iMac with a wireless mouse. After a couple years - it stopped working on my desk. I cleaned both the mac and desk - still no luck. Then I grabbed a glossy white loose leaf binder - and used it as a mouse pad. It works fine. Go figure. Matt white does not do it - glossy white does. I am guessing something is clogging the mouse eye.

Answer (score 1):

I am a programmer and the lack of easy glide with the magic mouse has been quite a problem. I've always had super-light touch mice/mouse-pads on Mac and Windows and it minimizes the effort used to move the mouse which is very desirable.
Apple understands the value of this minimum effort goal as evidenced by their keyboard. The keys are very easy to depress and travel a very small distance.

But the mouse was a real problem.
I have tried every surface imaginable short of buying an expensive piece of sheet metal which I was very skeptical of.

I did eventually buy the fliders and found them satisfactory. I use them on the smooth surface of my wood desk. But there is still undesirable friction. I had resigned myself to it.

Then today I decide to check if there were any new ideas online. I found this discussion and was intrigued by the idea of what was referred to above as "selotape". 
Could it be that simple ?

I placed a strip of 3M Scotch tape (the matte surface variety that you can write on) over each flider on the mouse. To my amazement it is a perfect solution. The magic mouse glides as perfectly as all my others. Incredible. So simple.

I am not sure if it would be just as good without the fliders. My guess is yes. But for now it feels so good I'm leaving the fliders under the tape. They do add a tiny bit of softness to the feel.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine by using the aluminum side of my old ipad that is too slow to use for much anymore, makes a great mouse pad though, works great now.

Answer (score 0):

Basketball shorts work perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

I have found an aluminium gaming pad to be cold, scratchy & not good - not that responsive or accurate. I had a really old, freebie branded mouse pad & that worked well. Magazines, tables, books etc all not good. Think the mouse pads you used to get given 10 years ago & you will be on the right track, with the foam under & the slightly hard & slightly shiny surface.

Answer (score 0):

Use any pad/mat but change the tracking on the mouse via **System Preferences > Mouse** settings to suit the pad. If it's slow across page move tracking over to fast.

Answer (score 0):

I use a placemat designed for putting your plate on at dinner. This works perfectly with magic mouse. The placemat has a hard surface on top that is very smooth and lets the two rubber/plastic strips on the underside of the mouse glide around with just the right amount of friction. It also has a cork backing that grips the table. It's the perfect (and cheap!) solution, plus you can shop around for different designs. Only drawback is that you may need to buy a set of 4.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to throw my recommendation in here because I recently started using a mouse pad that works really well

### [3M Precise Mouse Pad with Non-Skid Backing and Battery Saving Design-Bitmap - $5](http://radnex.us/3M_precision_mouse_pad)

[image]

I originally bought this because I needed a cheap mouse pad *without* kittens, puppies, or dolphins on it that I could throw in my briefcase  so I could use my mouse (Apple Magic Mouse and Microsoft Arc Mouse) when I was out and about.  Sometimes the work surface (like a picnic table) is impractical to use a mouse on.

**This thing actually works as advertised for only $5**  The tracking is excellent, but I was curious to see how well it extended my battery life.  I have a rechargeable battery that only holds a week's worth of charge (needs to be replaced).  When I put this pad in place, I got just over a week and a half with the same battery.

For the price, you can't beat this mouse pad.

Answer (score 0):

I use a standard mouse mat, fabric backed with rubber to prevent movement. £5 from the local stationery store.

Performance is much better than on the old, somewhat shiny mouse mat that I was replacing. I would see really odd Magic Mouse behaviour such as missed clicks and extra scrolling in certain apps.

Answer (score 0):

My magic mouse started being scratchy and it was driving me crazy. After trying some of the suggestions above, and going out and getting a gamers mouse-pad, I still wasn't happy. My solution was purchasing a plastic sign that had one side that is white with no printing. I cut it to size, put an even layer of double back tape on the print size and stuck it to my desk. Initially, the plastic was too shiny and the mouse didn't work right, so I used some 3-M sanding material, very fine material, and knocked the gloss off and it works perfectly! Low cost, custom size/shape, and no more scratchy mouse sounds.

Answer (score 0):

The glossy dust cover of the Chicago Manual of Style (15th edition) seems to work quite well.

Answer (score -2):

The perfect surface is simly a sheet of printer white paper laid on top of your 
regular mouse pad 1/8" thick rubber pad . FAST and ZERO effort !

Comment: Tried that, didn't work too well.